# Breaking apart code using yield return into different methods

Tags: c#, yield-return

I am implementing a fiber system for running game AI scripts and I ran into a small problem.

I am using yield return x to signify a wait x frames in the scripts. I wanted to encapsulate the logic of calculating x frames as other events can modify how many frames to wait. My ideal solution would be something as follows:

```
public Boolean removeScript = false;

public IEnumerable update()
{
    while(true)
    {
        shootAtPlayer()
        wait(30)
    }
}

private IEnumerable wait(int x)
{
    yield return removeScript ? -1 : x;
}
```

wait() either instructs to yield return 30 or returns -1 if the script is no longer needed. The iterator would handle the -1 return by removing the script. If x > 0 the iterator would decrement the return every frame until 0 then call update() again.

However this doesn't work as of course the yield return from wait() is not propagated to the update method. This leads to code duplication, worse modularity and less readable code:

```
public IEnumerable update()
{
    while(true)
    {
        shootAtPlayer()
        yield return removeScript ? -1 : x;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to structure this? or is there a language feature I am missing that would be useful in this case?

Comment: What exactly is the point of using `yield return` here? Who calls `update` and why can't it just be a plain old function?

Comment: The caller has an update loop (called once a frame) which calls update on the above scripts if the current Enumerator is 0. If the current enumerator is > 0 it decrements the enumerator once a frame until 0. The reason why it is implemented this way is to to allow the scripts to be written in a do this then wait 60 frames then do that way instead of a do this at frame 0 then do that at frame 60. It makes the scripts more easy to track as they operate sort of like separate subroutines. It is preferable to use yield return rather than spawning a thread for each script and using sleep e.t.c.

Comment: You are trying to create co-routines with yield. Unfortunately for you yield is a slightly limited version of co-routines. As you have discovered you can only have yield directly inside the body of the IEnumerable function, not nested into another method. This limitation makes sense if you think about what magic the compiler does behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, the solution is relatively simple: make `Wait()` return just the integer:

```
public IEnumerable Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ShootAtPlayer();
        yield return Wait(30);
    }
}

private int Wait(int x)
{
    return removeScript ? -1 : x;
}
```

In more complicated cases, you can use `foreach`, though this makes the syntax much more verbose:

```
public IEnumerable Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ShootAtPlayer();

        foreach (var x in Wait(30))
            yield return x;
    }
}

private IEnumerable Wait(int x)
{
    yield return removeScript ? -1 : x;
}
```

As you can see, you can (ab)use `yield return` to implement fibers, but `yield return` was never meant for this, so it won't work that well.

What was made for this kind of asynchronous continuations is the new `async`-`await`. With that, your code could look for example something like this:

```
public async Task Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        ShootAtPlayer();
        await Wait(30);
    }
}

private async Task Wait(int x)
{
    await fiber.Wait(removeScript ? -1 : x);
}
```

As a final note, I think the way you're using `removeScript` is not a good idea. End of a script should be signified by the `Update()` method actually completing (the enumerable doesn't have any more items, or the `Task` completes), not by returning a magic value.